# Shouldn't Eslint enforce props fields to be readonly in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

Say I have the following code snippet:

```
interface MyProps {
  label: string;
}

function MyComponent(props: MyProps) {
  return (
    <p>
      {props.label}
    </p>
  );
}
```

Neither Eslint nor the TypeScript compiler throws a warning or an error if I don't mark the fields in `Props` as `readonly`. Yet, component props should never be modified, otherwise the React UI engine won't work as expected.

This is with Eslint@6.8.0, React@16.13.1 and TypeScript@3.9.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should already be covered by the rule eslint(no-param-reassign)
My editor gives eslint error message as follows:

```
import React from 'react';

interface MyProps {
  label: string;
}

export function MyComponent(props: MyProps): React.ReactElement {
  props.label = 'hi'; // Assignment to property of function parameter 'props'.eslint(no-param-reassign)
  return <p>{props.label}</p>;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, although I would have loved for Eslint to complain if the interface lacks the `readonly` attribute in the first place.